# How to properly change code to use without delegate

Tags: c#, .net

There's the method UpdateAsync which executes from intermediate 2 methods. I want to execute UpdateAsync directly without depending on delegate in signature in order to make an opportunity to combine these 2 behaviors. UpdateType and UpdateNameAsync are not similar. How can I properly change it or get rid of delegate to make it possible?

```
public async Task UpdateBaseEntityTypeAsync(Guid id, Guid baseEntityId, IEnumerable<string> type)
{
    await UpdateAsync(id, baseEntityId, async x => x.UpdateType(type));
}

public async Task UpdateBaseEntityNameAsync(Guid id, Guid baseEntityId, string name)
{
    await UpdateAsync(id, baseEntityId,
        async x => await x.UpdateNameAsync(name)).ConfigureAwait(false);
}   

public async Task UpdateAsync(Guid aggregatorId, Guid baseEntityId, Func<BaseEntity, Task> updateAsync)
{
    var someAggregator = await someAggregator.TryFindById(aggregatorId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    
    var baseEntity = someAggregator.ListBaseEntities()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == baseEntityId);

    await updateAsync.Invoke(baseEntity).ConfigureAwait(false);

    await aggregatorRepo.Save(someAggregator).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I have done something like this, but I think it looks like crap:

```
public class BaseEntityDTO
{      
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Type { get; set; }
}

public async Task UpdateAsync(Guid aggregatorId, List<BaseEntityDTO> baseEntityDTO)
{
    var someAggregator = await someAggregator.TryFindById(aggregatorId).ConfigureAwait(false);

    foreach (var intent in intentsToEdit)
    {
        var baseEntity = someAggregator.ListBaseEntities()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == baseEntityDTO.Id);

        if (baseEntityDTO.Type != null)
        {
            baseEntity.UpdateType(baseEntityDTO.Type);
        }
        if (baseEntityDTO.Name != null)
        {
            await baseEntity.UpdateNameAsync(baseEntityDTO.Name).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }      
        await aggregatorRepo.Save(someAggregator).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Can it be done in some other way?

Comment: Can't really work out what you're asking. What do you want the solution to look like? Post your broken attempt

Comment: Both look equally good or bad to me. If your goal is to create 1 method call for the caller you can make the three methods in your first example private and wrap them in another public method. What I would have against the second example is using string list as a type denominator - but that is 1) not the issue of this question and 2) a matter of taste.

Comment: But then I still need to somehow exclude behavior in case of null value of a field?

Comment: You can use null-coalescing operator `??` to avoid `null` values to be setted. Smth like `baseEntity.Name = baseEntityDTO.Name ?? string.Empty;` and `baseEntity.Type = baseEntityDTO.Type ?? new List<string>()`.

Comment: This looks like what I needed. Thank you!